# creating notify icon in system tray and adding shortcut to startup using .net setup creation wizard

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I have searched a lot but still not able to find the right solution.

I want to create a setup using .net setup wizard and add 2 checkbox in the setup wizard.

1st checkbox will ask user to "add program in startup". If it is checked then it will add software to startup.

2nd checkbox will ask for "create system tray notify icon". If checked then it will create a notify icon in system tray. The notify icon must be displayed permanently not only when application runs).

I know it had to do with custom actions but still not able to figure it out. Please provide me some article or code for this with proper explanation.

Comment: The .Net installer tools are very basic and they don't support customizations like this.  You will need to get a more complete installation builder, something like InstallShield or NSIS.

Comment: @CodingGorilla Actually, this is very doable using the Custom Actions code secgment of the .NET installer.  You should be able to do both through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the custom actions is the right place to do this.  Here's the code I use to create two custom checkboxes during the installation process.

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
    public class DeploymentManager : Installer{



  public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver) {
     base.Install (stateSaver);


const string DESKTOP_SHORTCUT_PARAM = "DESKTOP_SHORTCUT";
const string QUICKLAUNCH_SHORTCUT_PARAM = "QUICKLAUNCH_SHORTCUT";
const string ALLUSERS_PARAM = "ALLUSERS";

        // The installer will pass the ALLUSERS, DESKTOP_SHORTCUT and QUICKLAUNCH_SHORTCUT   
        // parameters. These have been set to the values of radio buttons and checkboxes from the
        // MSI user interface.
        // ALLUSERS is set according to whether the user chooses to install for all users (="1") 
        // or just for themselves (="").
        // If the user checked the checkbox to install one of the shortcuts, then the corresponding 
        // parameter value is "1".  If the user did not check the checkbox to install one of the 
        // desktop shortcut, then the corresponding parameter value is an empty string.



        bool allusers = true; // Context.Parameters[ALLUSERS_PARAM] != string.Empty;
  bool installDesktopShortcut = true; //Context.Parameters[DESKTOP_SHORTCUT_PARAM] != string.Empty;
        bool installQuickLaunchShortcut = true;// Context.Parameters[QUICKLAUNCH_SHORTCUT_PARAM] != string.Empty;

if (installDesktopShortcut){
    // If this is an All Users install then we need to install the desktop shortcut for 
   // all users.  .Net does not give us access to the All Users Desktop special folder,
   // but we can get this using the Windows Scripting Host.
   string desktopFolder = null;
         if (allusers){
       try{
    // This is in a Try block in case AllUsersDesktop is not supported
    object allUsersDesktop = "AllUsersDesktop";
    WshShell shell = new WshShellClass();
         desktopFolder = shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref allUsersDesktop).ToString();
}
catch {}
  }
if (desktopFolder == null)
desktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPathEnvironment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);

CreateShortcut(desktopFolder, ShortcutName, Path.Combine(TargetAssemblyFolder, TargetAssembly), ShortcutDescription, Path.Combine(TargetAssemblyFolder, "your.ico"));
        }

        if (installQuickLaunchShortcut){
            CreateShortcut(QuickLaunchFolder, ShortcutName, ShortcutFullName, ShortcutDescription, Path.Combine(TargetAssemblyFolder, "your.ico"));
        }
    }

private void CreateShortcut(string folder, string name, string target, string description, string targetIcon){
string shortcutFullName = Path.Combine(folder, name + ".lnk");

try{
    WshShell shell = new WshShellClass();
    IWshShortcut link = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutFullName);
    link.TargetPath = target;
    link.Description = description;
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(targetIcon);

    link.IconLocation = Path.Combine(fi.Directory.FullName, fi.Name);
    link.Save();
}catch (Exception ex){
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The shortcut \"{0}\" could not be created.\n\n{1}", shortcutFullName, ex.ToString()),
    "Create Shortcut", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
}
}
```

After you have this code, you can add the Custom Action to the installer to the Install Custom Actions area.

The notification code would be similar for the install process but needs to be added to the registry.